# Small gallery for Logos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im looking for small and simple Logos gallery. Can you recommend me some very simple based on JQuery?

http://codecanyon.net/item/tonic-gallery-jquery-xml-portfolio-gallery/full_screen_preview/120710?ref=ibrandstudio

For example I don't need to open the image into full screen when I click on the Logo. I just need to display the logos as list.

Comment: Here a good photo gallery which could be used for your logos, it's very easy to use - http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: You can use this jQuery library: [nailthumb](http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb-demo.php)

Comment: You are hosting the logo art on your server?

Comment: @Robert No, on free web hosting.

Comment: @PeterPenzov  The [Flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) is really powerful and easy to use if you can host your logo there. See example image gallery here: [Creating an Image Gallery with the Flickr API](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-image-gallery-using-flickr-api-requirements-markup/)